# CollectionViewCellに一部角丸にしたラベルを表示させると重い

Tags: swift2, uicollectionview, uilabel

[image: 角丸のラベル]

写真のようなギャラリービューを作成していますが、
セルの画像とラベル（カスタムラベル）を角丸にし、同じようなUIにするとスクロールがとてももっさりと重くなります。
（参考にしたアプリではスムーズにスクロールしているのですが・・・）

おそらくセルの数だけカスタムラベル内で図形描画が走っているからなのではと推測しています。

ちなみに、通常のUILabelに変更するとスムーズにスクロールしてくれます。

カスタムラベルは
http://qiita.com/k-yamada@github/items/eb09485664d7207eb22e
をほぼそのまま流用して実装しました。

この問題を解決するためにはどのようなロジックを組めばいいのか、
ぜひご教授いただけると助かります。

以下コードを載せておきます。

【カスタムセル】

```
class UsersCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let imageView   = UIImageView()
    let statusLabel = CustomLabelClass()
    //let statusLabel = UILabel()

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addSubview(imageView)
        self.addSubview(statusLabel)

        self.setupCustomCellImage()
        self.setupCustomCellLabel()
    }

    // 画像の設定
    func setupCustomCellImage() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.imageConstraint()
    }
    func imageConstraint() {
        self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(imageView)

        let viewTop : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let viewLeading  : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let viewBottom    : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let viewTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

        self.addConstraints([
            viewTop,
            viewLeading,
            viewBottom,
            viewTrailing
        ])
    }

    // カスタムラベルの設定
    func setupCustomCellLabel() {
        self.statusLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.statusLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(0x000000, 0.7)
        self.statusLabel.setCornersAndRadius([.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], radius: 6.0)

        self.statusLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(CGFloat(10))
        self.statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        self.labelConstraint()
    }
    func labelConstraint() {
        self.statusLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(statusLabel)

        let viewHeight  : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: statusLabel, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16.0)
        let viewLeading : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: statusLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let viewBottom  : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: statusLabel, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let viewTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: statusLabel, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

        self.addConstraints([
            viewHeight,
            viewLeading,
            viewBottom,
            viewTrailing
        ])
    }
}
```

【カスタムラベル】

```
class CustomLabelClass: UILabel {

    var corners: UIRectCorner = [.TopLeft, .TopRight, .BottomLeft, .BottomRight]
    var radius: CGFloat = 0

    func setCornersAndRadius(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        self.corners = corners
        self.radius = radius
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: self.corners,
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.radius, height: self.radius))

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIBezierPathでマスクを作ってるのが原因のように思われます。

UILabelは通常のUILabelに戻した上で、UIImageViewとUILabelを入れるViewを別に作り、そのViewの四隅を普通に丸めるようにしてみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！

早速ご指摘の通りに実装しなおしてみたいと思います。

結果をまたご報告させていただきます。

Comment: ベースのUIViewを作ってその中にUIImageViewとUILabelをaddSubViewし、cornerRadiusを適用後、masksToBoundsを有効にしたら思い通りのスムーズスクロールとなりました！

この度は適切なアドバイスほんとうにありがとうございました！